# Whorlwind and RxJava2

Tags: android, github, dependencies, version, square

I have a question regrading RxJava2 support in WhorlWind. 
I am converting a project which uses Whorlwind from Rx1 -> Rx2. My current Whorlwind version in my root project gradle is 1.0.1, which according to their github CHANGELOG.MD is the only version.

https://github.com/square/whorlwind/commit/769ad313154df46ce07638dc79bd46ae14e5fbfb

As you can see, the commit above has made the changes to support rxjava2 however I am not able to find a version number to update in my gradle. There must be some key concept I'm missing because how I understand it, the Whorlwind library on my machine will remain at the RxJava1 build until I update the gradle to bring in some new Whorlwind library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with that library, what I did to move forward was to use the library the same way that the sample app that they have uses it. By adding the library to your project and referencing the library from there.

See their build.gradle here:
https://github.com/square/whorlwind/blob/master/whorlwind-sample/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks for responding, that could work. I will also post the solution I found as an answer

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/square/whorlwind/commit/47961437c611abc4ec88c900cdb6621ef6662b1c

In the gradle.properties, Square lists a snapshot of a newer version that supports Rx2. I'm not sure why they don't list it in the ChangeLog or ReadMe